# Expired Session Redirect in Tapestry 4

Tags: tapestry

How can you change the page displayed by Tapestry 4 when the user's session expires?

Answer (score 3):

Ah, the old days, Tapestry 4...

I think there were different ways..

- just name the page you want to display "StaleSession.html", or
- put something in your app.application file.. like

  `<page name="StaleSession" specification-path="tapestry/page/StaleSession.page"/>`

or

- put something in your hivemodule.xml, like

`<contribution configuration-id="tapestry.InfrastructureOverrides">
 <property name="staleSessionPageName" value="MyStaleSessionPage" />
</contribution>`

hth

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check if the user is logged in or something similar, you can set a property in your Visit object, and check for it in the `validate(IRequestCycle cycle)` method of your pages. If there are several pages, create a superclass for all the pages you want to redirect when there's no user logged in, and implement the method in the superclass. Remember that whenever you call `getVisit()` you get a new instance if there isn't any, so you need to set a property in your Visit object to see if the session is valid.

Comment: Yes. That checks for logged in. But tapestry has its own 'Your session is expired, please try restarting the session' page that is relatively ugly and I just want to bounce users to my login page.